# Device Manager Blue Screen when disabling WiFi device

Tags: windows-10, bsod, device-manager

The particular device is the RTL8821CE 802.11ac adapter that is built into this HP laptop.  The moment I click OK after choosing Disable Device, there's a blue screen, after which, the computer reboots, and...the WiFi adapter is still there (or, Windows "fixes it" for me).

The use case is that I have another Wi-Fi dongle as part of a test system in a controlled environment, and I need to ensure that the internal adapter never gets used.

The kicker, which will hopefully eliminate a lot of unnecessary questions is, that this is one of 6 identical systems, the laptops having been bought together.  None of the other 5 had any problem when I did this.

Comment: "I need to ensure that the internal adapter never gets used." - Remove the actual device.  You can disable the antenna connected to the RTL8821CE and physically remove it.

Comment: It should look like  https://c1.neweggimages.com/ProductImage/AK42_1_201905011910121085.jpg but we don't know if you'll have easy access to it if you decide to open the laptop up

Comment: Try, instead if disabling, uninstalling the device.  Even if it blue screens, Wireless should be gone upon restart. See if that works.

Comment: My suggestion is to disable it in the UEFI firmware (AKA BIOS) and not worry about WHY it didn't disable properly elsewhere (life is short).